# Exception while trying to get data from a URL

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba, that gets a URL. The URL (if inserts into a browser) downloads a .csv file.
The vba should get the data of that .csv file from the URL, and it adds the data to a new sheet.

This is the code that have to connect to the URL and get the data:

```
            With Sheets(currentSymbol).QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
                "TEXT;" & URL _
                , Destination:=Sheets(currentSymbol).Range(dataAddress))
                .Name = ""
                .FieldNames = True
                .RowNumbers = False
                .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                .PreserveFormatting = True
                .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
                .SavePassword = False
                .SaveData = True
                .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                .RefreshPeriod = 0
                .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
                .TextFilePlatform = 850
                .TextFileStartRow = 2
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
                .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
                .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
                .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
                .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
                .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9)
                .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            End With
```

If I use the following URL (that returns a .csv file), it works fine:

http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=SPY&startdate=Jan+1%2C+2000&enddate=Dec+31%2C+2017&num=30&ei=WLQtWaAfiMOxAbeYutgE&output=csv

But if I use the following URL (which also returns a .csv file), I get an exception:

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/SPY?period1=1476219600&period2=1508533200&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=uqY5qLCvV0S

CurrentSymbol and dataAddress in both cases is the same.
URL holds the url.

The second URL does exists and does return a .csv file.

I have a pre-check for the URL that completes fine (for both the URLs):

```
Function HttpExists(sURL As String) As Boolean
    Dim oXHTTP As Object
    Set oXHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

On Error GoTo haveError
oXHTTP.Open "HEAD", sURL, False
oXHTTP.send
HttpExists = IIf(oXHTTP.status = 200, True, False)
Exit Function
```

The exception that I get from the second URL says:

```
Error 1004: Microsoft excel cannot access the file "https://.........."
There are several posible reasons:
* The file name of path does not exist
* The file is being used by another program
* The workbook you are trying to save the same name as a currently open workbook
```

What can be the problem with the second URL?

Why do I get the exception for the second URL?

Thanks

Comment: HTTPS is encrypted. You may have to download the CSV file, then open it and read it.

Comment: Is there a way to do it automatically? It is a script that pass through more than 1000 URLs like that..

Answer (score 0):

The second URL only returns a .csv file when your browser has the right cookie. Excel probably can't provide cookie, so it gets a warning in JSON.

Comment: Thanks.. Is there a way to do it automatically? it is a script that pass through more than 1000 URLs like that

Comment: You could probably skip it using the old `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: But I don't want to skip it.. I need the data from the .csv.. is there a way to use it?

Comment: Now that's a different question. I can't find anything about that. Knowing Microsoft I suspect Excel to access the cookies from IE. So if you can get the data in IE you might also get them in Excel. But that's just guessing.